# Can't find definition

Tags: visual-c++

I have written sveral units that are dependant on definition like

```
#ifdef aaa
...
#endif
```

Now I have added these units into my project and expecting that code in secton aaa will be grayed since I didn't make `#define aaa`. But this not happened? Searching code for `#define aaa` gives nothing. How to find this hidden definition?

Comment: You should give it a more descriptive name.

Comment: Check `Project > Properties > C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`